# SQL Query Help: Need to write a query for the below described problem

Tags: sql

Lets say i have table called Orders

```
id      qty1    qty2     qty3
-----------------------------------
1       1        2        3
2       0        1        0
3       3        2        1
```

Result of the query should be as following (Note qty are sum column wise for qty)

```
productID  qty
----------------
1           4
2           5
3           4
```

Please help me to make query?

Comment: There is no clear relationship between your table and the query results. Have you entered the desired output correctly? Also, tag this as homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a very strange table design, and the results you want are even stranger. But this should do it:

```
SELECT 1 AS productID, SUM(qty1) AS qty FROM Orders

UNION

SELECT 2 AS productID, SUM(qty2) AS qty FROM Orders

UNION

SELECT 3 AS productID, SUM(qty3) AS qty FROM Orders
```

If you would specify the type of SQL (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc...) server than I might be able to produce a neater query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any way I can do it without hard coding for productID?

Comment: UNION won't combine the values summing each column -- it'll just omit duplicates.

Comment: @NsM: do you really have 1 column per product? And if you do, which database server are you using?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: there is no difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` here since the rows will never be equivalent. This should return exactly the output specified by MsM.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT o.productid, 
         COALESCE(SUM(o.qty1), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(o.qty2), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(o.qty3), 0) AS qty 
    FROM ORDERS o
GROUP BY o.productid
ORDER BY o.productid
```

Assuming that a qty# column value could be NULL, that requires insulating your query from returning NULL because some databases don't like adding NULL, a placeholder for a non-existent value, to a valid integer value.  Omit the `COALESCE` after you test first, or confirm that the columns are not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it only typo what you do not have ProductID in Orders....

```
SELECT productID, (qty1 + qty2 + qty3 ) AS  qty FROM Ordrers .....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT qty1 + qty2 + qty3 FROM Orders GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id as product_id, (qty1 + qty2 + qty3 ) as qty from orders;
```